# Replication Monitor reports little to no latency, but my tracer token is taking hours to go from Distributor to Subscriber

Tags: sql-server, replication

I sent a tracer token through a replication job that was reporting about 2 seconds of latency about two and a half hours ago.  I sent the token through because I noticed a row that was inserted on a published table had not been sent to the replicated table.

I'm not sure what this indicates and would appreciate any help in troubleshooting it.  Thank you.

**UPDATE**: 
My replication publication hasabout 30 tables. Most of these tables are being replicated as expected. When I run a trace I can see their sp_MSupd_dboXXXXX procedures running, I can verify that the data is in sync.

However, for several tables, this is not happening. When I looked in the database the table was being replicated to, it did not even have its own sp_MSins, upd, and del procedures.

When I run sp_browsereplcmds and provide its publication_database_id and article_id, I can see that the command is waiting to be run.

For example, it might say {CALL sp_MSins_dboTableName (fields here)}. It will sit there for a while, then disappear.

My first assumption was that it wasn't being applied because the procedure didn't exist. So I wrote my own sp_MSins_ proc to confirm this (@c1 datatype, @c2 datatype etc...) and tested it to be sure it worked.

But even then, when I do an insert, the command sits in the repl_commands table for a while, then disappears, and no row ever hits my table.

I'm getting pretty lost here. Can anyone help? Thanks!

Some more detail:

The distribution DB lives on the subscriber. There are several publications from the same database on the publisher to the same database lon the subscriber (three to be exact, two work fine, one does not).

On two of the publications, a tracer token is processed within about 4 seconds. On the one I'm having trouble with, the tracer token hangs in limbo indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

For my money, tracer tokens are a really good way to monitor latency. I don't know what the latency metric in replication monitor is measuring, but I've personally found it to be unreliable. For my environment, I post a tracer token through a SQL Agent job and then monitor the token's progress by looking at the token tables in the distribution database.

Comment: As expected, the token is in the distribution database but won't commit to the subscriber.  I don't know how to debug the cause of this, though.

Comment: People think replication is magic. It's not; it's just another application making inserts, updates, and deletes (through stored procedures) in your database. So treat it as such. Is there blocking? A bad query plan (e.g. parameter sniffing) for one or more of the procs? Fire up a trace and see what's happening. That all assumes that there aren't any errors as far as the repl'n monitor is concerned and that the distribution agent is running...

Comment: One other thing to keep in mind; there is a clock ticking. Specifically, the minimum retention property on the distribution database is when repl'n is allowed to start trimming. So you may want to increase that while you troubleshoot.

Comment: I know it's not magic, it's just very strange for me.  I'm noticing that there are procedures used by replication to actually apply updates, named like: sp_MSupd_dboTableName.  But curiously, I do not see any with the table names of the ones I am having trouble with.  I think I should probably try to trace the token stored procedure, but I'm having trouble figuring out which procedure processes tokens.

Comment: Don't get me wrong; that wasn't meant as anything towards you personally. People just get intimidated because "replication is hard". So you're seeing the commands being applied at the subscriber. Tracer tokens are just marks made in the transaction log at the publisher that the log reader and distribution agents process. Dumb question, but are you subscribing to all articles in the publication? IIRC, tokens don't get processed if you don't subscribe to the first article in the publication.

Comment: Wow!  The first 11 article_ids are not in mssubscriptions for the publisher_database_id i'm having the issue with.

Granted, I don't know the significance of this, or how to add them or when they were meant to be added.  I'm kind of inheriting replication from our sysadmin team.

Comment: I logged a connect item a while back for this very issue (same issue which causes me to know that you need to be subscribed to the first article to get tokens to commit at the subscriber). The response was that it's an unsupported configuration to not subscribe to all articles in a pub. So my advice: either get rid of the unsubscribed to articles, subscribe to them, or move them to their own publication.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to subscribe to them for a while. It doesn't seem very well-documented.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28133/discussion-between-ben-thul-and-aushin)